# Prove almost surely convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_i$, $i\ge1$, be i.i.d random variables, $X_i\ge0$, $E(X_i)=1$, $Y_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{X_k}$. Prove that if $P(X_1=1)\lt1$, $Y_n$ converges to 0 almost surely. 
I don't know how to start, please help.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It is is easy to verify that $(Y_n)$ is a martingale. Any non-negative martingale converges a.s. so $Y=\lim Y_n$ exists almost surely.

Now $$\log Y= \lim log Y_n=\lim \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \log X_k$$ $$=\lim k\frac  1 k\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \log X_k.$$ By SLLN's $\lim \frac  1 k\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \log X_k =E\log X_1$. By Jensen's inequality $E\log X_1 \leq \log EX_1= 0$. If  $E\log X_1 = 0$ then $X_1=1$ as, contradicting the hypothesis. Hence $[\lim k\frac  1 k\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \log X_k]=-\infty$ a.s. which means $Y=0$ a.s..